# How to add a new column with null value to Eloquent query result? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm doing a basic join query and want to add organization_id column with null value.

```
$user = User::select(
    'users.id as id',
    'users.personnel_id as personnel_id',
    'agency_users.agency_id as agency_id',
    'null as organization_id',
)
->join('agency_users', 'agency_users.user_id', 'users.id')
->where('users.id', Auth::id())
->first();
```

Although I can get the result I want in Postgresql query, I get the following error in Laravel:

`SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "null" does not exist`

Comment: Try with: `"'null' as organization_id"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's as simple as the following code:

## Add fake column you want by this command

```
$data = $data->addSelect(DB::raw("'fakeValue' as fakeColumn"));
```

So your code will become:

```
$user = User::select(
            'users.id as id',
            'users.personnel_id as personnel_id',
            'agency_users.agency_id as agency_id',
        )
        ->addSelect(DB::raw("'null' as organization_id"))
        ->join('agency_users', 'agency_users.user_id', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', Auth::id())
        ->first();
```

Take Care.